# Loading JSON files to Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use the copy command to load a bunch of JSON files on S3 to redshift. Example structure of the JSON file is:

```
 {
 message: 3
 time: 1521488151
 user: 39283
 information: {
     bytes: 2342343
     speed: 9392
     location: CA
 }
 }
```

Is it possible to create a table with the correct columns - splitting up the information block to individual columns as well and use copy command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 8, Redshift Spectrum Supports JSON format directly queryable from Redshift as external tables.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/amazon-redshift-spectrum-now-supports-scalar-json-and-ion-data-types/

Documentation on how to mount S3 JSON files to Redshift.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

Thanks Scott for providing the reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: redshift spectrum can take json just fine

Comment: @JonScott You are very correct. Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: @JonScott Thank you very much for the reference. Referring it got added on March 8th. With cloud, you are always outdated.

Comment: Parquet still provides some performance benefits over json.  If you need them, spectrify might be a useful tool to help convert: https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify